# SQL Server SELECT query ordering by substring

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a SQL Server table that has the following rows:

MyColumn : `C1_xxx1,C2_xxx1,C3_xxx1,C1_xxx2,C1_xxx3,C3_xxx2`  etc

It is a `text` column that contains strings that have the following format: `CY_mystring` where Y is a number from 1 to 5, followed by the '_' character then `mystring` that can have any value.

Is there a way to make a select return this column ordered as following:

```
C1_xxx1
C1_xxx2
C1_xxx3
......
C1_xxxn
C2_xxx1
......
C2_xxxn
C3_xxx1
.......
C3_xxxn
```

etc

Ordered by the `CY_` substring.

thank you

Comment: I dont understand why `ORDER BY MyColumn ` does not work.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter : because life it is so simple sometimes and we tend to make is complicated. Thanks,it worked!

Comment: @Tim, `xxx` is arbitrary per record (*as i understand it*) and the OP needs the last char taken into consideration for sorting..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it .. (order first by the first two chars, and then by the last char (*assuming that the final `n` is always one digit long*))

```
SELECT
   Column1
FROM
   TABLENAME
ORDER BY
   LEFT(Column1,2) ASC, 
   RIGHT(Column1,1) ASC
```

Comment: +1 After re-reading the question, this looks like the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You say that Y is a number from 1 to 5 it's always one character long.  Assuming the format is `xY_xxxZ`, you can order on `Y` then `Z` like:

```
order by 
        substring(MyColumn,2,1) -- Second digit
,       right(MyColumn,1) -- Last digit
```

If `Z` can be longer than one character (i.e. 10 or higher) you can use `pathindex` to determine the number of digits at the end:

```
order by
        substring(MyColumn,2,1) -- Second digit
,       right(MyColumn, patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(MyColumn))-1) -- Digits at end
```